# Select multiple ids from a PostgreSQL sequence

Tags: postgresql, select, nextval

Is there a concise way to select the nextval for a PostgreSQL sequence multiple times in 1 query?  This would be the only value being returned.

For example, I would like to do something really short and sweet like:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('mytable_seq', 3) AS id;
```

And get:

```
 id  
-----
 118
 119
 120
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
select nextval('mytable_seq') from generate_series(1,3);
```

generate_series is a function which returns many rows with sequential numbers, configured by it's arguments.

In above example, we don't care about the value in each row, we just use generate_series as row generator. And for each row we can call nextval. In this case it returns 3 numbers (nextvals).

You can wrap this into function, but I'm not sure if it's really sensible given how short the query is.

Comment: Note that the 3 numbres (nextvals) are not guaranteed to be sequential.

Answer (score 15):

There is a great article about this exact problem: "[getting multiple values from sequences](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/03/20/getting-multiple-values-from-sequences/)".

If performance is not an issue, for instance when using the sequence values dwarfs the time used to get them or *n* is small, then the *SELECT nextval('seq') FROM generate_series(1,n)* approach is the simplest and most appropriate.

But when preparing data for bulk loads the last approach from the article of incrementing the sequence by *n* from within a lock is appropriate.

Comment: Interestingly, that article appears to be written by the person who wrote the answer I accepted :-)

Regardless, the generate_series fits my need because the number of ids I need is around a dozen.  On a very rare case, maybe 100... so the downfalls of the other solution presented in the article are too steep for my uses.  +1 for nice link though!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really want three rows returned I would set the sequence to 'INCREMENT BY 3' for each select. Then you can simple add 1 and 2 to the result have have your three sequence numbers.

I tried to add a link to the postgresql docs, but apparenty I am not allowed to post links.

Comment: Appreciated, but the downfalls pointed out in the link from Ants Aasma are too steep for me to alter the increment... and the number of ids I need varies, so I prefer obtaining all the ids individually (which makes the code that uses the ids simpler anyways).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
DECLARE
    seqval int; x int;
BEGIN
x := 0;

WHILE x < 100 LOOP
    SELECT into seqval nextval('f_id_seq');
    RETURN NEXT seqval;
    x := x+1;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Of course, if all you're trying to do is advance the sequence, there's [setval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-sequence.html).

You could also have the function take a parameter for how many times to loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(loopcnt int) RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
DECLARE
    seqval int;       
    x int;
BEGIN
x := 0;
WHILE x < loopcnt LOOP
    SELECT into seqval nextval('f_id_seq');
    RETURN NEXT seqval;x := x+1;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Comment: Note that due to the use of 'setof', you have to call this as a table:

`select * from foo(500);`

Answer (score 0):

My current best solution is:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('mytable_seq') AS id
UNION ALL
SELECT NEXTVAL('mytable_seq') AS id
UNION ALL
SELECT NEXTVAL('mytable_seq') AS id;
```

Which will correctly return 3 rows... but I would like something that is minimal SQL for even as much as 100 or more NEXTVAL invocations.